# Excel Reference Problems Publishing VB.NET 2015 Program

Tags: vb.net

I am at the point where I need to publish my program and share it with a team of people. The problem is I reference and excel file to calculate data in the program. I cannot figure out how to share the program without including specific instructions on where to put the excel file in their file system.

I have tried adding the file using the "Setup Wizard" but i'm not sure then how to reference the file path if I include the excel file.

I have also tried importing the excel file to the program, but cannot figure out how to call it to open when it is a resources instead of a file location.

```
Public APP As New Excel.Application
Public worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
Public workbook As Excel.Workbook
workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Plant Simulator\Database\Raw Data.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to place the file in the installation directory and refer to that path with a [VB.net command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa457089.aspx):

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)
```

Comment: So where I currently have: 
`Public APP As New Excel.Application
    Public worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Public workbook As Excel.Workbook

workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Plant Simulator\Database\Raw Data.xlsx")`

Replace with `workbook = System.IO.Path.Get...`??

Comment: @Mark We can't tell you where to insert the code unless you edit your question and provide some code so we can help you!

Comment: Sorry about that! Just forgot to add in the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

I used the "Setup Wizard" and added my excel file "Raw Data.xlxs" as a reference.

Instead of using:
`workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open("C:\Desktop\Plant Simulator\Database\Raw Data.xlsx")`

I used this and it worked.

`workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\Raw Data.xlsx")`

Comment: Consider using the `System.IO` namespace to use `Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "Raw Data.xlsx")` It's neater and safer when bringing path strings together.